# Post Name to php MYSQL database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, unity-game-engine, upload

If I upload a set of letters, this php script dies with error|5, but if I use numbers for the $phpSign variable, everything works perfectly.

```
<?php
$device = $_POST["device"];
$randomChar = $_POST["randomChar"];
$phpSign = $_POST["Sig"];
    if($mysql->query("UPDATE premium SET signup = $phpSign WHERE (id, randomChar) = ('$device', '$randomChar')")) die("success");
    else die("error|5");
?>
```

Why can;t I upload names with the scripts, and why will it only work with numbers? How can I upload a name to my database?

Comment: Why are you using `multi_query` when there's just a single query?

Comment: You can do all this in one query, with `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Comment: Why don't you put `randomChar` in the `INSERT` statement?

Comment: randomChar is to ensure it goes to a unique user, just incase somebody wants to change their ID. And noted, I updated the code and removed the unnecessary bits. I've also refined my question, because for some reason words won't upload, but values will. Otherwise, it dies with error|5 instead of success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need quotes around `$phpSign`, since it's a character, not a number.

```
    if($mysql->query("UPDATE premium SET signup = '$phpSign' WHERE (id, randomChar) = ('$device', '$randomChar')")) {
        die("success");
    } else {
        die("error|5:" . $mysqli->error);
    }
```

As I've shown, when the query fails you should display the MySQL error message, not just a generic error message. That way you'll know why it failed.

P.S. You should learn to use prepared statements instead of substituting variables, then you wouldn't have to worry about quoting, as well as avoiding SQL injection problems.

Comment: Can you update your comment based on the code I edited? I just changed it, and I'm afraid the part you cite isn't a part of the script anymore.

Comment: That worked! I'm glad it was something simple. I do wish I was better at debugging php scripts, but I'm incredibly novice at the moment. I'm assuming ". $mysqli->error" adds to the original basic error, and gives a more in depth debug? If so, that's awesome, and will come in very handy. Thanks again